# New release full of fatal errors - Fatal error: Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: error, ee3, fatal

I just started a fresh site with ExpressionEngine 3.0.6 and it seems like everything I do creates a Fatal Error. They are all the same error too.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function on a non-object
```

This is the case with the simplest of tasks such as avatar selection. It also happens when I try to save settings inside of addons. The "function" it references is always different, depending on the task at hand, but the error is the same. If EE wanted to be more OO, I understand that, but breaking things on a $300 license is killing me.

Is there any kind of "simple" fix to correct the non-object references?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What version of PHP is the installation server running?

Comment: Sounds more like your environment. Can you provide some information on that?

Comment: Currently on WAMP, local development, PHP Version 5.5.12  --- Apache Version : 2.4.9 --- PHP Version : 5.5.12 --- Server Software : Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 --- MySQL Version : 5.6.17 --- EE Version 3.0.6